# How to use ggplot to boxplot a gene expression dataframe subsetting only a specific gene and dividing my samples in 2 conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm new at R and I have some basic question related to bloxpot. I have a data frame 9800 obs. (these are genes) of  17 variables (these are my samples), and the expression values for those genes. I put a simplified example below.

```
View(df) 

           sample1   sample2  sample3  

gene1         1         2        25

gene2        5.2        5        32

gene3        3.1        3        50

gene4        2.5       2.6       21
```

First, I want to associate each sample with a specific condition (responder or no-responder). In this case samples 1 and 2 will be responders and sample3 non-responder. Would work if I create a data frame like this?

```
condition <- c('responder','responder','non-responder')
sample_condition <- cbind(colnames(df), condition)
View(sample_condition)

sample     condition

sample1    responder

sample2    responder

sample3    non-responder
```

Now, I want to use ggplot to do a boxplot that shows the expression values of gene1 for the 2 conditions I have designed. [example of the boxplot I want. I would like to include the dots for each sample as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzLKZ.png)

I think my question is really how to tell ggplot() to plot df subsetting only a specific gene and dividing my samples in the 2 conditions I have previously designed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/89-box-and-scatter-plot-with-ggplot2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example data

```
df <- data.frame(sample1=runif(4),
                 sample2=runif(4),
                 sample3=runif(4))
rownames(df) <- c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4")

        sample1    sample2   sample3
gene1 0.7068424 0.81313273 0.1021884
gene2 0.2212768 0.87664923 0.3599538
gene3 0.7835704 0.08712978 0.7942733
gene4 0.3909335 0.70202803 0.8851641
```

Define your responders and non-responders

```
responders <- c("sample1","sample2")
nonresponders <- setdiff(colnames(df),responders)
```

Filter for only `gene 1` and label entries

```
library(tidyverse)
gene1 <- df[1,] %>%
           gather() %>%         
       mutate(category=ifelse(key%in%responders,"responder","nonresponder"))
```

Make plot

```
qplot(x=category, y=value, data=gene1, geom=c("boxplot","jitter"), fill=category)
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack,
looks like you need to convert from wide to long format data first and then create a boxplot.  I'm going to use a couple packages from Hadley Wickham in the [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org/) to make this happen.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- gather(df, condition, values, -condition)
ggplot(df, aes(condition, values))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

Once the base plot is made, you can add the points on top with some transparency or `alpha` and some "wiggle" around the vertical axis to make them show up better and some color.

```
ggplot(df, aes(condition, values, color = condition))+
  geom_boxplot(outler.fill = F, alpha = .5)+
  geom_jitter(alpha = .5,width = .1)
```